# Why is sin(X + 100 Quantillion) a straight line?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

I was messing around in Desmos, inputting random numbers in to the sine function just to pass the time. So, I inputted:

$sin(x + 1000000000000000000)$  (100 quantillion)

and I was confused to as to why this was a straight line? Is this just an error with the calculator or is this mathematically correct? If so, why?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $f(x+\alpha)$ is $f(x)$, translated. The straight line is probably due to numerical issues.

Comment: it's not a straight line. It is just some scale settings, or artihmetic error with desmos dealing with such large numbers, but the actual graph itself looks like the usual sine graph, just shifted that many units to the left.

Comment: Until you get close, the $x$s are insignificant so the sine function looks like the sine of a constant which is a horizontal line.

Comment: @abs It is in this case because Desmos is rounding.

Comment: Hmm, how do calculators calculate $\sin$?  If the use some sort of algebraic approximation, this seems reasonable.  The difference between $10$ and $15$ is that $15$ is $50\%$ larger than $10$. so if demos considers those numbers to be fairly different.  But the difference between $1000000000000000010$ and $1000000000000000015$ is that $0.0000000000000005\%$ larger.  That's such a small degree of difference that demos can't handle it.  ... Or so it seems reasonable to me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems